# Saving Plist data using Archiver vs creating a readable (xml) file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've finally managed to save my data using NSCoding and a plist file.
However, the solution (cobbled together from various tutorials) uses an Archiver so the resulting plist file is binary.

I'd like to save the data in a text/readable plist xml file (at least for testing purposes) since I can read it.

How can I change my code to do this?

My "encodeWithCoder" and "initWithCoder" methods are in my Class designation.

My AppDelegate uses this to save the data where "allMsgs" is an array of Class instances:

`NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:allMsgs];
    [encodedObject writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];`

The AppDelegate uses this to read the data:

`NSData *codedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    if(codedData!=nil){
        allMsgs = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:codedData];
    }`

Comment: You'd want to save a dictionary (`NSDictionary`) to disk instead of saving `NSData`.

Comment: @sudorm-rf Not sure what you mean. Do you mean "allMsgs" must be of type Dictionary, or do you mean "encodedObject" must be of Type Dictionary?

Comment: what type of data has the allMsgs variable?

Comment: @Artanis allMsgs is an NSMutableArray

Comment: great then, you can use the example I provided below to add that Array into the dictionary and save it as plist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can save your data in a plist:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docFilePath = [documentsDirstringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserSettings.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

// add the data to dict here
[dict setObject:allMsgs forKey:@"allMsgsKey"];

// save the data as plist
[dict writeToFile:docFilePath atomically:YES];
[dict release];
```

Since a plist is actually represented by a NSDictionary your data must be able to be stored in a dictionary.

Comment: That didn't save anything. I think the problem is the data contained in allMsgs is Class Instance data containing int, BOOL, NSString, and UIColor. I'm pretty sure it has to be handled using NSCoding.

Comment: A plist can only store objective-c data types, not custom classes. So if you wish to save your data in a plist you can stick it in a NSData object but that won't help in your case (you want to read the plist data)

Comment: New weirdness - I went back to using the Archiver, and when I located the plist file in the Finder, and selected it, I got an XML preview in the Finder window! I can use 'QuickLook' from the finder to see the XML...

Comment: You can open the plist file in Xcode but it won't mimic the finder's view behavior.